# Pass the scipy.signal.stft data to librosa.feature.melspectrogram

Tags: python, scipy, librosa

My source code is like this below.

it shows error like

```
librosa.util.exceptions.ParameterError: Audio data must be floating-point
```

I am not clear yet for how to set librosa.feature.melspectrogram argument.

How should I alter??

```
sample_wave = './data/mywave.wav'
wav=wave.open(sample_wave)

data=wav.readframes(wav.getnframes())
data = np.frombuffer(data,dtype=np.int16)
f,t,stft_data=sp.stft(data,fs=wav.getframerate(),window='hann',nperseg=256,noverlap=128)

S = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(y=stft_data, sr=44100, n_mels=128, hop_length=256, n_fft=128) # It shows the error

log_S = librosa.power_to_db(S, ref_power=np.max)
print(log_S.shape)
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 4))
librosa.display.specshow(data=log_S, sr=sr, hop_length=hop_length, x_axis='time', y_axis='mel')
plt.colorbar(format='%+2.0f dB')
plt.title('Mel spectrogram')
plt.tight_layout()
```

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to pass the spectrogram in `y` which accept only audio array data (run `help(librosa.feature.melspectrogram)` for more informatio).

```
y : np.ndarray [shape=(n,)] or None
        audio time-series
```

where you should use `S`

```
S : np.ndarray [shape=(d, t)]
        spectrogram
```

change the line into:

```
S = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(S=stft_data, sr=44100, n_mels=128, hop_length=256, n_fft=128)
```